# How to update magento2 to magento 2.0.1 from admin?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

How to update Magento2 to Magento 2.0.1 from admin?

Like we updating on older version

Please Help me to update magento2 to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_201-upgrade.html

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

For the admin method, you can check on the link below

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html